# How can I get the maximum light while avoiding heat from a window?

Tags: lighting, insulation, windows

I have a west facing window. How can I get max light while avoid any heat coming from it?

Answer (score 2):

To reduce heat gain from the sun, you need a window with a good "low e" rating (also called low emissivity). You can get similar results on an existing window by adding a film that reflects IR.

You also want multi-layer windows to block heat transmission (a lower U value is better, it's the inverse measurement of an R value you see on insulation). And finally, you should make sure that the window has good weather stripping to block any drafts, causing a direct heat loss/gain to your home.

[Here's an article](http://robjundt.hubpages.com/hub/How-To-Understand-Window-Energy-Ratings) that describes this in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try an after market installation of some of the newer low E films before replacing a window with factory applied coating.

You have 2 competing factors that cannot both be optimized: 
Visual transmittance (VT) and Solar heat gain coefficient (SHGC)

> > Two measures of a film’s energy performance are visible transmittance (VT) and solar heat gain coefficient (SHGC), which range from a unitless measurement that is between zero and 1. A higher VT value indicates greater amount of visible light passing through the film, while a lower SHGC means more solar radiation is rejected by the film. Mid-range products with VT and SHGC values around 0.5 are “ideal for northern climates,”

and

> > Films where VT greatly exceeds the SHGC are suitable for hot climates

[Excerpted from Eco building pulse article](http://www.ecobuildingpulse.com/window-film/beyond-the-surface.aspx)