# How do I maximize light gain and minimize heat gain for my glass wall?

Tags: air-conditioning, energy-efficiency, temperature, glass, energy-audit

How to get maximum benefit of daylight while optimizing air-conditioner benefit for a glass wall (currently) of size 11' * 8' (total 88 square feet exposed).

Facts:
The glass wall never gets direct sun rays.
The external temperature (in summer) is around 45 Celsius.
The indoor temperature is 35 Celsius.
The target temperature of Air conditioner is 23 Celsius.

Comment: UV/reflective coating if you want light but not heat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28590/how-can-i-get-the-maximum-light-while-avoiding-heat-from-a-window